# Can I see status of my flag on post of chat-room?

Tags: support, chat, flag-history

On S.E. sites I can see my flag's status by `http://[xyz].com/users/flag-summary/[user-id]` which can show flag status on specific site `[xyz].com` if I logged in.

But my account on https://chat.stackexchange.com/ , There is no page like `https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/[user-id]` available.

I probably only one time flagged on a post of [chat-room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS3Om.png). Can I see status of my flags on post of chat-room? If yes, then How to?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't see the flags you raised on chat messages. As a matter of fact the url for the [current flagable messages](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/admin/flagged?show=all) is even so hidden that you can only reach that if there is a flagged message for you.

As soon as the chatmessages got enough *Valid/Invalid/Not sure* actions they disappear into who-knows-where.

Keep in mind that chatmessages are less formal and each room has different values for what is accecptable and not which makes keeping a history of those flags not  important.